# how to implement sql like "select a from table1 where (a,b) in ( (1,1),(2,2) )" in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

like this way:

```
q = session.query(table1).filter(table1.a==1).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that you propose

```sql
SELECT a FROM table1 WHERE (a, b) IN ((1, 1), (2, 2))
```

does not seem to be valid in SQLite.  From the docs on [row-value comparisons](https://sqlite.org/rowvalue.html#row_value_comparisons):

> For a row-value IN operator, the left-hand side (hereafter "LHS") can be either a parenthesized list of values or a subquery with multiple columns. But the right-hand side (hereafter "RHS") must be a subquery expression.

However, assuming you're happy to use a query on the RHS, this would work:

```py
with Session() as s:
    subselect = (
        s.query(Table1.a)
        .filter(
            sa.or_(
                sa.and_((Table1.a == 1), (Table1.b == 1)),
                sa.and_((Table1.a == 2), (Table1.b == 2)),
            )
        )
    )
    q = s.query(Table1).filter(sa.tuple_(Table1.a, Table1.b).in_(subselect))
```

The key parts are

- using [tuple_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) to construct the row-value on the LHS
- using a query to construct the RHS*

For a backend that does support row values, like PostgreSQL, you can do this:

```py
with Session() as s: 
    q = s.query(Table1).filter(
        sa.func.row(tbl.c.a, tbl.c.b).in_((sa.func.row(1, 1), sa.func.row(2, 2)))
    )
    for row in q:
        print(row.a, row.b)
    print()
```

---

* While SQLite requires a subquery on the RHS, SQLAlchemy requires that we use a query or select construct in this situation; using subquery elicits a warning:

> SAWarning: Coercing Subquery object into a select() for use in IN(); please pass a select() construct explicitly